# Java class for computing stock indices

Tags: java, stock, indices

Anyone knows where can I find open source Java class for computing stock indices like simple moving average, weighted moving average etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://commons.apache.org/math/

Answer (score 1):

I developed a Java library for technical analysis: [ta4j](http://github.com/mdeverdelhan/ta4j-origins)

It comes with lots of indicators, including: Aroon, ADX, ATR, Bollinger bands, moving averages, parabolic SAR, stochastic oscillators...

See [these examples](https://github.com/mdeverdelhan/ta4j/wiki/Usage%20examples#playing-with-indicators) for indicators manipulations.

Comment: Ta4j is not maintained by me anymore. Find the new organization here: https://github.com/ta4j

Answer (score 0):

The things you mention (SMA, Weighted Moving average) are not indices in the way that, say, Dow Jones 30 and S&P 500 are indices.

Simple and Exponential Moving Average are very easy to compute, and if you're just starting out in Java, I'd suggest you try your hand at it.

You might try [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=stock%20averages) to see what others are doing and join in.

Answer (score 0):

- [Lidgren](http://ltsa.sourceforge.net/) - technical analysis
- [NexTick](http://nextick.sourceforge.net/) - ticker with some analytics
- [Data Visualizer](http://dataviews.sourceforge.net/) - charting